# Display image beyond dropdown div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm really new on web development and I want my image to be displayed beyond a dropdown div. I already tried to set the image's position to relative, overflow-visible, but nothing worked for me. Here, I'm using tailwindcss and alpinejs.
[image]

This is the trade dropdown's code:

```
<!-- Trade -->
<div 
  class="hidden md:flex sm:ml-6"
  id="nav-heading"
  aria-labelledby="nav-heading"
  x-data="{ tradeOpen: false }"
  :aria-expanded="tradeOpen"
>
  <button 
    type="button" 
    class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base font-bold leading-3 text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out border-b-2 hover:border-indigo-500 focus:no-underline lg:text-lg hover:no-underline hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:text-gray-900"
    :aria-expanded="tradeOpen"
    aria-controls="nav-list"
    @mouseenter.prevent="tradeOpen = !tradeOpen"
    @click.away="tradeOpen = false"
  >
    Trade
  </button>

  <div 
    x-show.transition.in.duration.100ms.origin.top.left.opacity.scale.10.out.duration.100ms.origin.bottom.right.opacity.scale.10="tradeOpen" 
    id="nav-list" 
    class="absolute w-auto origin-top-left rounded-md shadow-lg top-16"
  >
  <!--
    Trade dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.
  -->
    <div class="py-1 bg-white rounded-md shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">Básico</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">A Forma Mais Fácil de Realizar Trades</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">Clássico</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Interface simples e fácil de usar, perfeita para iniciantes</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">Avançado</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Acesso completo a todas as ferramentas de trading em uma única tela</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">Margem</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Maximize os lucros com alta alavancagem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">OTC</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Melhores preços e maior liquidez para grandes trades</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">P2P</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Transferência bancária e 100+ opções</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the image's code within its wrappin divs:

```
<!-- Collapsible Warning -->
<div class="w-full my-4">
   <div x-data={show:true} class="rounded-sm">
      <div :class="{'border-b-0': show}" class="flex flex-row justify-between px-10 py-4 bg-gray-100 border align-center" id="headingOne">
         <div class="flex items-center mx-auto">
            <h4 class="mb-0">Termine de configurar sua conta Exchange</h4>
         </div>
         <button @click="show=!show" class="focus:outline-none" type="button">
            <svg x-show="!show" class="w-5 h-5" id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 451.111 451.111" height="512" viewBox="0 0 451.111 451.111" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m290 0 56.389 56.389-88.611 88.611 48.333 48.333 88.611-88.611 56.389 56.389v-161.111z"/><path d="m145 257.778-88.611 88.611-56.389-56.389v161.111h161.111l-56.389-56.389 88.611-88.611z"/><path d="m306.111 257.778-48.333 48.333 88.611 88.611-56.389 56.389h161.111v-161.111l-56.389 56.389z"/><path d="m161.111 0h-161.111v161.111l56.389-56.389 88.611 88.611 48.333-48.333-88.611-88.611z"/></svg>
            <svg x-show="show" class="w-5 h-5" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
               width="489.682px" height="489.682px" viewBox="0 0 489.682 489.682" style="enable-background:new 0 0 489.682 489.682;"
               xml:space="preserve"> <g><g><polygon points="31.38,339.21 110.117,339.21 0,449.325 36.898,486.222 147.013,376.108 147.013,454.843 199.193,454.843 
                     199.193,287.03 31.38,287.03"/><polygon points="458.302,339.21 458.302,287.03 290.488,287.03 290.488,454.843 342.669,454.843 342.669,376.108 452.782,486.222 
                     489.682,449.325 379.564,339.21"/><polygon points="458.302,150.472 379.564,150.472 489.682,40.357 452.782,3.46 342.669,113.574 342.669,34.839 290.488,34.839 
                     290.488,202.652 458.302,202.652"/><polygon points="147.013,113.574 36.898,3.46 0,40.357 110.117,150.472 31.38,150.472 31.38,202.652 199.193,202.652 
                     199.193,34.839 147.013,34.839"/></g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>

      <div 
         x-show.transition.in.duration.500ms.origin.top.right.opacity.scale.1.out.duration.500ms.origin.bottom.left.opacity.scale.95="show" 
         class="grid grid-rows-3 gap-0 px-8 py-4 overflow-x-auto border border-t-0 sm:px-10 sm:py-6 sm:grid-rows-1 sm:gap-8 sm:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-6"
      >
         <div class="flex flex-col items-start justify-between col-span-1 py-4 border-b sm:border-transparent sm:py-0">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
               <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
                  <img class="w-10 h-10 lg:w-12 lg:h-12" src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/100/000000/1-c.png"/>
                  <h4 class="mb-0 text-sm leading-5 text-indigo-800 lg:leading-6 lg:text-lg">Verifique sua Conta para Negociar Moeda Fiat</h4>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-row items-start mt-4">
               <img class="transform scale-75 sm:scale-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/id-verified.png"/>
               <div class="flex flex-col ml-4">
                  <p class="text-xs text-black md:text-sm">Verifique sua identidade para negociar moedas fiat (como Dólar ou Euros) e aumentar seus limites de depósitos e retiradas.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-24 h-8 px-1 py-1 mt-4 font-medium text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out bg-indigo-500 border border-transparent rounded-md sm:w-44 sm:h-10 sm:px-6 sm:py-3 text-md lg:text-base hover:bg-indigo-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700" type="button">
               <a href="#" class="text-xs text-white sm:text-sm lg:text-base hover:no-underline focus:text-gray-300 focus:no-underline hover:text-gray-200">VERIFICAR</a>
            </button>
         </div>

         <div class="flex flex-col items-start justify-between col-span-1 pt-2 pb-4 border-b sm:border-transparent sm:py-0">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
               <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
                  <img class="w-10 h-10 lg:w-12 lg:h-12" src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/100/000000/2-c.png"/>
                  <h4 class="mb-0 text-sm leading-5 text-indigo-800 lg:leading-6 lg:text-lg">Deposite em sua conta</h4>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-row items-start mt-4">
               <img class="transform scale-75 sm:scale-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/deposit.png"/>
               <div class="flex flex-col ml-4">
                  <p class="text-xs text-black md:text-sm">Deposite criptomoedas e faça sua primeira negociação.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-24 h-8 px-1 py-1 mt-4 font-medium text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out bg-indigo-500 border border-transparent rounded-md sm:w-44 sm:h-10 sm:px-6 sm:py-3 text-md lg:text-base hover:bg-indigo-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700" type="button">
               <a href="#" class="text-xs text-white sm:text-sm lg:text-base hover:no-underline focus:text-gray-300 focus:no-underline hover:text-gray-200">DEPOSITAR</a>
            </button>
         </div>

         <div class="flex flex-col items-start justify-between col-span-1 pt-2 sm:pt-0 sm:py-0">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
               <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
                  <img class="w-10 h-10 lg:w-12 lg:h-12" src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/100/000000/3-c.png"/>
                  <h4 class="mb-0 text-sm leading-5 text-indigo-800 lg:leading-6 lg:text-lg">Proteja Sua Conta</h4>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-row items-start mt-4">
               <img class="transform scale-75 sm:scale-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/safe.png" />
               <div class="flex flex-col ml-4">
                  <p class="text-xs text-black md:text-sm">A Verificação em Duas Etapas para Login mantém sua conta protegida ao adicionar mais um método de autenticação.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-24 h-8 px-1 py-1 mt-4 font-medium text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out bg-indigo-500 border border-transparent rounded-md sm:w-44 sm:h-10 sm:px-6 sm:py-3 text-md lg:text-base hover:bg-indigo-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700" type="button">
               <a href="#" class="text-xs text-white sm:text-sm lg:text-base hover:no-underline focus:text-gray-300 focus:no-underline hover:text-gray-200">PROTEGER</a>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a CSS position and z-index to the dropdown menu to make sure that it's always on top.

Comment: I've set z-50 for the dropdown and z-10 for the image, but it didn't work. What am I missing about the positions? The dropdown's position must be absolute, so the dropdown doesn't go floating through the page, but what about the image's position?

Comment: Currently I'm missing some parts of the code to make sure that I'm giving you a correct answer. Do you have an URL where I can see your exact case? Or could you provide some more HTML & CSS? There might be a z-index issue on some other parts of your page because setting a position and z-index should normally work. The z-index on the image shouldn't be needed by the way.

Comment: I updated the code so you can check out the image's wrapping elements. Unfotunately, StackOverflow doesn't allow the whole code as it's really big (tailwindcss and svg images makes it rly big)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by setting position: relative and z-index:0 on the image's div and z-index:10 on the dropdown